# Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 10)

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow 
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Dense

x = np.stack([np.random.choice(range(10), 10, replace=False) for _ in range(5)])
y = np.stack([np.random.choice(range(10), 10, replace=False) for _ in range(5)])
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(5,10), return_sequences=False))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(12,  activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid')) 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(x,y)
```

My input and output shape is (5, 10) and dimension is 2.
When I try to execute above code the following error message occurs:
`ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Your input should be of size 3 for a LSTM: [batch_size, nb_timesteps, nb_features].
The input_shape argument specify the size of each instance which is [nb_timesteps, nb_features], but the lstm expect batch of instances so the tensor you send in should have an dditional batch_size dimension like [batch_size, 5, 10]